# SSH failing authentication after manual edit of /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

Recently, I needed to add a user to our CentOS server. For some reason, I could not add or remove them using useradd or userdel, so I edited /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow manually, adding them. I was then able to use passwd as root to change their password, and all was well.

Or so I thought. Now, some users aren't able to log in via SSh at all - when prompted for their password, they're given `Permission denied, please try again.` for three attempts, then `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).`

This may be unrelated to the changes to /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow - removing the changes to those files doesn't solve the problem.

EDIT 1: The new user is able to log in via ssh, but some older users (including root) are not. The problem is also ONLY with ssh - logging in on the physical machine, and using su, both work without problem.

Comment: When you say you edited them directly, I assume you mean you edited the files with vi (or another editor), and not with [vipw](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vipw)?

Comment: Yep, used vi. Also directly copied another user line, changing userid and groupid to new numbers.

Comment: If you _absolutely_ _must_ edit these files directly, always use vipw.

Comment: @Bryan What does vipw do that editing the files in vi does not, other put a lock on the file for all users? I don't see why that would make a difference in this case. Also, auth is working on the physical box, just not through ssh, so I don't think the problem actually lies in those files, now.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge it doesn't do anything else, it is however considered to be 'good practise' to edit these files this way, and only if you _must_ edit the files. As for `useradd`, it would help if you detail the error message you receive. Are there any other clues in any log files as to what might be going on?

Comment: There's nothing of note in /var/log/secure, other than the normal pam authentication failure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think adding users manually to `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` is a bad idea. Those users may face troubles sooner or later. Also, you may mistype some records. I am not sure what will be the result in this case.

I recommend you to restore these files to the old state if possible and retry adding those users using `useradd` command.

Comment: Adding the user using useradd was failing. I don't remember what the error was off the top of my head, but it was **not** `useradd: user  exists`. Edited the question with a bit more information, if that helps you.

Comment: i'd suggest looking into that error before this workaround bites you in the butt.

Comment: @sirex Deleting the user using userdel worked, but trying to readd it with useradd gave `useradd: user exists`. I'm not sure what's causing the problem here. I deleted the home directory as well, and still can't useradd the user.

Comment: Created http://serverfault.com/questions/350291/unable-to-add-user-using-useradd

Answer (score 5):

Run `pwck` and `grpck` to check for formatting errors on the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files, respectively. This also checks the relevant shadow files.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible reasons come to my mind:

1. Your changes to `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow` are somehow malformed.
2. You forgot to change users home directory owner with `chown -R user` after changing their uid. File system stores uid numbers, not user names.

Comment: The new user is able to log in, but some older users are not. The problem is also ONLY with ssh - logging in on the physical machine, and using su both work without problem. Editing the question to include this information

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this could be a reason, but it is still worth trying:

Are you having **SELinux** switched on ? Because, if the context gets changed, many apps would have trouble accessing the files.