# I edited /etc/passwd and have strange problems

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, users, passwd

I manually edited `/etc/passwd` for non-root user - yeah, I know this is bad.
Unfortunately I saw this ([SSH failing authentication after manual edit of /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow](https://serverfault.com/questions/350276/ssh-failing-authentication-after-manual-edit-of-etc-passwd-and-etc-shadow)) very late.
I already recovered `/etc/passwd` to previous state, but something strange is happening on the server, for example:

```
useradd some_user
```

doesn't create home directory for this user, and doesn't ask about it password, authorization for old user is not working.
I hope someone already encountered such a problem.
P.S. I use Debian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the manpage for adduser:

useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.

Answer (score 6):

`useradd` doesn't create the user's home directory by default, nor does it ask for a password. You can pass the `-m` flag to create the home directory, and just run `passwd` after creation to set the password.

`man useradd` will tell you more, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

next time if you must edit /etc/passwd use

```
vipasswd
```

Comment: it will verify things are ok.. same with sudo.. `visudo`